# jQuery Mobile with Expression Web 4 versus Dreamweaver CS5.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver, expression-web

Is there a way to get Expression Web 4 to work with jQuery Mobile the way jQ Mobile works with Dreamweaver?

For example, if you have the  tags referencing jquery and jquery mobile in the  Dreamweaver environment, it just understands that `<div data-role="page" id="myPage"></div>`
is valid code for my jquery mobile project.  In Expression Web, it is complaining that `data-role="page"` isn't a valid attribute in HTML 5.  That might be the case, but the Dreamweaver environment isn't complaining about it and it is even providing auto-complete as well.